# Why doesn't the given example in firestore work as per the documentation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null &&
        getAfter(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/countries/$(request.resource.data.country)
        ).data.last_updated == request.time;
    }

    match /countries/{country} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }    
    }
}
```

I have tried to do the database as follows:

```
countries/{country}
fields : last_updated

cities/{city}
fields :Populations, country
```

If I change the population of a city, it should automatically update the **last_updated** field of the particular country.

But it is not happening?
I referred this tutorial: [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0)

Answer (score 1):

The security rules you defined only enforce whether or not a document read/write is allowed; they don't actually modify a document's data. So your rule

```
match /cities/{city} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid != null &&
    getAfter(
      /databases/$(database)/documents/countries/$(request.resource.data.country)
    ).data.last_updated == request.time;
}
```

just says "allow the city document to be written if, at the end of the transaction or batch write, the corresponding country's `last_updated` field has also been updated."

In your client-side code, you need a transaction (or batch write) that (1) writes to the city document, and (2) updates the country's last_updated time.